# When i click outside my element will not unvisible

Tags: javascript

i have got a div. If i click the show button the div vill be visible. I find a solution to hide div when i click outside the element, but it is not work, what i do badly?

```
function login_show(){
    let y = document.getElementById("login");
    if(!y.style.display || y.style.display == "none"){
        y.style.display = "block";
    }
    else{
        y.style.display="none";
    }}          
window.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(!document.getElementById("login").contains(event.target)){
        document.getElementById("login").style.display="none";
    }
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You forgot the 'event' parameter in callback function.
2. If the show button is outside of the div, you should consider it in the callback function, may be like:

   `if(!document.getElementById("login").contains(event.target) && event.target !== document.getElementById("showButton"))`